# Traer ultimo registro de una tabla con eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Hola** estoy tratando de traer el ultimo dato de mi tabla pero al retornar veo que lo trae como tipo array y no entra a la validación, como podria solucionar esto.

Adjunto el codigo:

```
$credentials=tbl_usuario::select('rol')->orderBy('usu_id')->take(1)->get();

    //$credentials=DB::select('select rol from tbl_usuario order by usu_id desc limit 1')->get();

    if ($credentials =='Lab Catálisis' or $credentials =='Lab Suelos' or $credentials =='Lab Biotecnología' or $credentials =='Lab Análisis petrofísicos') {
        $lab = new tbl_lab();
        $lab->lab_ceco = $request->ceco;
        $lab->lab_direccion = $request->direccion;
        $lab->lab_lider = $request->lider;
        $lab->lab_usu_id = tbl_usuario::max('usu_id');
        $lab->save();
        return view('login');
    }
    return $credentials;
```

Esto es lo que me retorna la variable $credentials:

```
[{"rol":"Lab Cat\u00e1lisis"}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para obtener el ultimo elemento necesitarás otras funciones, ademas de que siempre te traerá un objeto asi sea solo un elemento

Debes obtener el ultimo registro con `first`

```
$credentials = tbl_usuario::select('rol')->orderBy('usu_id', 'desc')->first();

//El condicional ahora deberás apuntar a $credentials->rol;
//Para ahorrarte muchos OR, puedes usar la función in_array
if (in_array($credentials->rol, ['Lab Catálisis', 'Lab Suelos', 'Lab Biotecnología', 'Lab Análisis petrofísicos'])) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te esta pasando es que get() te devuelve un array de por si y luego estas comparando un array con un string, de ahi el error. E aqui unos ejemplos para que sepas como funciona el [ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent).

**->get()**

```
$users = App\User::where('active', 1)->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->name;
}
```

**->find($id)**

```
$user = User::find(1);

var_dump($user->name);
```

-**>first()**

```
$comments = Post::find(1)->comments()->where('title', '=', 'foo')->first();
```

**->all()**

```
$users = User::all();
```

**->count()**

```
$count = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->count();
```

Estos son ejemplos de los más comunes pero tambien tienes variantes de ellos como puede ser:

- findOrFail($id)
- firstOrFail()

Que basicamente si no encuentra lo que se busca devuelve una excepción. Esto puede ser interesante si quieres enviar al usuario a tu página de 404 personalizada.

> Teniendo esto en cuenta tienes que hacer un foreach de $credentials y
>   comporarlo en el if

```
    foreach($credentials as $example){
      if ($example =='Lab Catálisis' or $credentials =='Lab Suelos' or 
$credentials =='Lab Biotecnología' or $credentials =='Lab Análisis petrofísicos') {
      $lab = new tbl_lab();
      $lab->lab_ceco = $request->ceco;
      $lab->lab_direccion = $request->direccion;
      $lab->lab_lider = $request->lider;
      $lab->lab_usu_id = tbl_usuario::max('usu_id');
      $lab->save();
      return view('login');
     }
}
```

Todos los ejemplos son sacados del link que te dejo. Espero que te sirva :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo más simple en este caso es pasar entre corchetes el valor de la columna que se desea recuperar es decir

```
$credentials["rol"];
```

De modo que de la colección devuelta solo tome el calor que corresponde a la clave declarada entre comillas.

O bien cambias como ya te dijeron get por first y puedes asignar el aCceso de dicho valor a una propiedad así

```
$valor = $credentials->rol;
```

Y posterior usar en tu condicional a la propiedad $valor;

También puedes dejar de usar orderBy y en su lugar aplicar latest que ordena igual tomando la columna de created_at así

```
$consulta = Modelo::select("rol")->latest()->first();
```